# VSCode VIM Plugin doesn't register multiple leader key presses

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I'm using the VSCode VIM plugin with easymotion enabled and my leader key set to space. To trigges easymotion, I use the default way of hitting the leader key twice. So to use easymotion I would need to hit space twice and then follow with a motion to tell it in which direction I want to move.

Most of the time this workst fine. But very regularly, I hit space once and then VSCode VIM won't register my next space tap, but only the one after that. It's super annoying when you are in flow while editing and I just spent half an hour trying go replicate it reliably without success.

The first thing I'd like to know is if anyone else is experiencing this? And the second thing of course is how to solve it. It would be enough to know what is causing this most likely even, right now I kind of feel like I'm going crazy.

Answer (score 14):

I am aware that 3 months have passed, maybe you haven't solved or this reply my help other.

I have a **Macbook Air M1**, I had the same problem I was going crazy, I solved thanks to a guy on reddit...

So you should go into **System Preferences** -> **Keyboard** -> [Click the **text** tab] -> at the right there are 3 checkbox you should **uncheck** the last one **"Add full stop with double space"**

[image: Image showing the process described above]

On macOS Ventura, looks like this setting has moved a bit. It's under **System Preferences** -> **Keyboard** -> [scroll to Text Input Area, and click **Edit...** next to Input Sources] -> **uncheck "Add period with double-space"**

[image: Image of macOS keyboard input sources settings menu pane]

Comment: Oh.my.god. I may actually have a tear in my eye right now. I had already accepted my fate, but this actually seems to have worked. Amazing, thank you so much for posting this here, even after 3 months!

Comment: Really happy, I had the same sensation I thought that I had a broken space bar and I have kinda accepted it, but yeah thanks God hahaha

Comment: Could you please upvote my answer? thanks

Comment: Actually I can't. I tried but it says that I don't have enough credit yet?

Comment: Ah ok I get it, strange, As far as I know you can only If you are the one who asked the question btw thanks no problem

Comment: uncheck "Add period with double-space"

Answer (score 2):

On macOS ventura, looks like this setting has moved a bit. It's under **System Preferences** -> **Keyboard** -> [scroll to Text Input Area, and click **Edit...** next to Input Sources] -> **uncheck "Add period with double-space"**

[Image of macOS keyboard input sources settings menu pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYhrD.png)